# how do I target column names passed in an array to construct DB query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I hope this makes some sense, I've been working with this code for some days and am currently feeling slightly dispraxic!

I have a massive form that passes loads of info into a DB, an integral part of the form concerns file uploads.

I am creating an array called uploads and passing the column names from my database in the hope that I can use them to generate a query that will automatically enter any information it recieves into the corresponding column.

Here is an example of the code for my fields:

```
<label>Upload copy front page of contract and relevant special condition(s)</label>
    <input type="file" name="upload[UploadCopyContr]" value="<?php echo $out['UploadCopyContr']?>" />
```

The array is processed on the recieving end and the files are uploaded to the required folders without any issues, what I am having problems with is how to target the column string dynamically so I can produce my query string.

This would be the kind of query I would hope to end up with:

```
UPDATE $table SET $column = $value WHERE
```

So how do I extract the column name from my array and get it in a variable? If I var_dump ($_FILES["upload"]); I get the following response

```
["name"]=> array(4) { ["UploadCopyExtr"]=> string(9) "test2.pdf" ["UploadCopyContr"]=> string(9) "test1.pdf" ["UploadCopyTaxDesigLttr"]=> string(0) "" ["UploadOthTaxDesigDoc"]=> string(0) ""
```

So I know the values are there in the array, I just have no idea how to target them!

I could use $_FILES["uploads"]["UploadCopyExtr"] but thats no good for a dynamically generated query.

This is my file upload code - which is working perfectly.

```
$path = 'uploads/'; 
foreach ($_FILES["upload"]["error"] as $key => $error)
{                                                          
   $tmp_name = $_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        {
           if (!$tmp_name) continue; 
        }    
   $name = $_FILES["upload"]["name"][$key];

if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
{
    // Check if directory exists and create it if not.
    if(!is_dir($path . $_POST["AccountID"] ."/". $_POST["PropertyID"])) {
        mkdir($path . $_POST["AccountID"] ."/");
        mkdir($path . $_POST["AccountID"] ."/" . $_POST["PropertyID"] ."/");
    }
    if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $path . $_POST["AccountID"] ."/". $_POST["PropertyID"] ."/".$name))

        $uploaded_array[] .= "Uploaded file '".$name."'.<br/>\n";

    else
        $errormsg .= "Could not move uploaded file '".$tmp_name."' to '".$name."'<br/>\n";

}
else $errormsg .= "Upload error. [".$error."] on file '".$name."'<br/>\n";
}
```

I havn't included an example of my query since I have no problems with that aspect of the problem, I just want to know how to dynamically target those column names, forgive me if the 2 are intrinsically linked, I'm happy to provide whatever information is needed.

Comment: Can you provide a practical example of what you want to achieve? It is not very clear what `dynamically target the column names` means.

Comment: i am interested in how you will sanitize the column names which will come from client.... forgot to add, _lazyness in programming brings evil_

Comment: @itachi Not sure I need to sanitize column names client side, am using PDO so if any column names are passed that don't exist in the database it just stops the query, the worst that could happen is a partial insert. Please enlighten me if I'm wrong

Comment: you can not parametrize clumn names even in PDO. So you will be wide open to any SQL injections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use array_keys to get the keys of the array. You can also use implode to combine the keys into a part of the query. Basically:

```
$columns = implode( ', ', array_keys( $array ) );
// This nets you 'ColumnName1, ColumnName2, Etc, Etc2'
```

And the same for the values. Then insert these strings into the query.

Make sure, however, that you handle any errors the DB throws at you and screen values you insert into it.

The end-user CAN manipulate form HTML, and, as such, modify the column names that will be inserted into the query.